# KeyError in DataFrame groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've seen a few similar answers concerning KeyErrors from using groupby in DataFrame. However, their solutions and explanations don't fit my issue properly.

I find this particularly strange because I can't replicate the exception when I'm testing the script in the Python console, by feeding it with code line by line. The groupby attempt works normally when tested with one-entry examples.

Additionally, I had *earlier used the same script for a similarly-formatted json, though with significantly smaller data size - and it worked seamlessly*.

**What am I trying to do?**

I have a nested json string that I'm attempting to format using DataFrame, count the number of times a specific value appears in each column.

The json when put through a converter looks like this:

```
action,timestamp,campaign_id,title,type,url
open,2019-02-08T08:57:59+00:00,192a39071b,[CAMPAIGN TITLE],,
sent,2019-02-08T07:00:00+00:00,192a39071b,[CAMPAIGN TITLE],regular,
sent,2019-02-07T11:00:00+00:00,2159592071,[CAMPAIGN TITLE],regular,
open,2019-02-07T08:33:44+00:00,214d84380b,[CAMPAIGN TITLE],,
open,2019-02-07T08:33:19+00:00,56ab3a5934,[CAMPAIGN TITLE],,
open,2019-02-07T08:32:33+00:00,811ac6cae3,[CAMPAIGN TITLE],,
sent,2019-02-07T02:45:00+00:00,214d84380b,[CAMPAIGN TITLE],regular,
sent,2019-02-05T02:30:00+00:00,56ab3a5934,[CAMPAIGN TITLE],regular,
```

(in case it's relevant - the json is pulled directly from an API and not written in a csv or anything)

**Specifically, I want to count the number of times "open", and "sent" appear under the column for "action".**

This is the relevant snippet of the code I used:

```
dretrieved = json.loads(response.text)

dframed = pandas.DataFrame(dretrieved['activity'])

actionssummary = dframed.groupby('action').size()

try: opencount = actionssummary['open']
except:
    opencount = 0

try: sentcount = actionssummary['sent']
except:
    sentcount = 0
```

And this was the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MC_member_data_list_api.py", line 92, in <module>
    actionssummary = dframed.groupby('action').size()
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 7622, in groupby
    observed=observed, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 2110, in groupby
    return klass(obj, by, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 360, in __init__
    mutated=self.mutated)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 578, in _get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)
KeyError: 'action'
```

Anyone has a clue what's going on?

**EDIT**: Following suvayu's comment about Heisenbugs caused by unexpected or malformed input, I added an Exception-pass to my code as below, so that it would record a zero (0) for that user's entry and move on to the next:

```
    dframed = pandas.DataFrame(dretrieved['activity'])
    # identify action portion of the json (go to next if error)
    try: actionssummary = dframed.groupby('action').size()
    except:
        pass



    # identify count of opens
    try: opencount = actionssummary['open']
    except:
        opencount = 0
```

Comment: There is typo - space after `'action '` like `dframed.groupby('action ').size()`

Comment: Besides the typo pointed out by @jezrael, often in the case of an intermittent bug (Heisenbug), malformed/unexpected input is to blame.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake - the space after "action" was what I'd tried out when noticing in another question that the source material had a trailing space but the parameter in the argument didn't. The error persists with and without the trailing space.